# Trim the space after Select-String commande PowerShell ( for removing multiple local git branch)

Tags: git, powershell

My objective is removing all branch starting with 'fea'.

`PS> git branch`

```
  bug/5646
  chin-dev
* dev
  fea/account-manager
  fea/animation
  fea/charts
  fea/chat
  fea/dataTable
  fea/enquete
  fea/page-title
  fea/questionnaire
  fea/style
  hotfix
  master
  merge
  mod/dataTable
  question
  saif-dev
  support
```

The commande i tried

`PS> git branch -d $(git branch | Select-String -Pattern 'fea/')`

(Yes, I kown Select-String is matching string, but anyway ignore in that case)

Result with the commande

```
error: branch '  fea/account-manager' not found.
...
error: branch '  fea/questionnaire' not found.
error: branch '  fea/style' not found.
```

As you can see it return the matched line also with space.
So these anyway removing space with select-string?

Also i tried convert the result toString for using Trim()

```
PS > $(git branch | Select-String -Pattern 'fea/' ).ToString().Trim()
System.Object[]
```

Comment: Don't use `git branch` (a porcelain command) for writing scripts; use `git for-each-ref`. You'll find it much more suited to these things. You'll still need PowerShell-specific instructions (which I don't know) but other than this general Git advice, this is not a Git question at all, it's just a PowerShell question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can list a set of branches using `git branch` alone (and no external commands) :

```
git branch --list "fea/*"
```

2. `git branch` now supports the [`--format=...` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---formatltformatgt), which makes it much more suitable for scripting purposes (e.g: no need to do manual processing of the output to remove a leading `*` or leading spaces):

```
git branch --format="%(refname:short)" --list "fea/*"
```

---

As far as Powershell line processing goes :

to apply some action on each line (or each object) produced by a command, you should iterate on the output using `% { ... }` (short for [`for-each-object { ... }`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)) :

```
... | % { $_.ToString().Trim() }
```

Comment: I don't remember how `%(foo)` is interpreted in a double quoted string in Powershell, you may need to use single quotes, or to escape the `\%`.

Comment: Thanks!  it do extactly what i need, but i'm still curieuse to know if these someway to do Trim() after a select-String ( if these no other answer i'll mark this answer as a solution)

Comment: @WolfCode : you don't want to trim spaces from *the complete output*, you want to do this line by line. If I recall some Powershell correctly, that would be `... | % { some treatment on $_ }` (`%` is a shortcut for [`for-each-object`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)). So probably sth like : `... | %{ $_.ToString().Trim() }`

Comment: Thanks ! it work perfectly !! can you also add `| %{ $_.ToString().Trim() }` in your answer ?